# Is there a way to change the colour for specific characters for normal code or text

Tags: python, python-idle

I've been learning python in codeacademy and I like how for specific characters i.e. = , () they have a different colour to the rest of the text, however in IDLE it is all the same colour so it is a bit harder to follow. Is there a way to change this or is there a compiler out there similar to the codeacademy one?

Comment: Are you specifically wanting color on Idle, or have you tried other IDE/code editors?

Answer (score 0):

IDLE colors code in different roles: keyword, builtin, string, comment, and some others, but not specific characters.  You can customize the colors IDLE uses, but not the roles.  I suspect that the same is true for other Python IDEs, but don't really know.  If you want the codeacademy syntax units, you will have to look further.